# Qt progress bar - display double value

Tags: qt

I have to show the instantaneous value of a sensor output using a `QProgressbar`.

value can change from `0` to `0.3`

how do I configure (set range and set value) the `QProgressBar` to display the above value.

I'm a bit confused because `setRange` method can only take `int` values,  and how do I set range as `0` and `0.3`?

Comment: 0.3 could be a 30% if the max value is 1.0

Comment: You can multiply your preferred min/max values by 10 or 100 to make them integers. Then you just need to divide by the same before you display the current value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different way. You can chose between these two options:
Transform your range in an integer range by multiplying by 100

> `[0 , 0.3]` -> `[0 , 300]`
> When you receive a new value, just multiply it by 100
> `0.12*100` = `120/300`

---

You can also make `setRange(0, 100)` and for each value, make the conversion:

> ***(value * maxValue) / 100***
> So  `(0.12 / 0.3) * 100` give you 40%